# Template group parsing index file even when not called

Tags: templates, stash, parsing

I'm experiencing some strange behavior with one of my template groups.

There are two templates in the group, index and award. When loading the award template I am seeing content from the index file also displayed. The index file has PHP output switched on but this template shouldn't be getting parsed at all right?

In addition the award template first checks to see if a user is logged_out and displays a login form. However this condition is never being met, it's always seeing the user as logged_in even when not.

Any ideas what could be going on?

Answer (score 1):

I found out why the index file was being parsed. I using Stash to render my templates and I was missing the closing tag for exp:stash:set for this partial!